# Function to change nav icon when state = active not working (Javascript Wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bootstrap-4, nav

Looking to replicate a nav menu like this: https://stringworkshop.co.nz/
With pegs changing when the page state = active (and on hover).

The below code is working for hover, but not for the active state (it reverts back to the home page peg - see here: https://dev.stringworkshop.co.nz/).

Any help appreciated - my javascript is not the best!..

```html
<div class="scroll d-none d-lg-block">
    <img src=" @asset('images/menu.jpeg') " style="padding-left: 10px;">
    <div class="is_active">
    <a href="/" class="other" id="scroll_index" data-link="">
        <div class="flex-container flex-menu-width">
            <div class="flex3 no-padding">
                <img src=" @asset('images/unmarked.png') "  class="contact-menu">
                <span class="menu-content-adjust">Home</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="is_active">
    <a href="/luthier"  class="other" id="scroll_maker" data-link="luthier">
        <div class="flex-container flex-menu-width">
            <div class="flex3 no-padding">
                <img src=" @asset('images/unmarked.png') " class="luthier-menu">
                <span class="menu-content-adjust">Luthier</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="is_active">
    <a href="/violin-making" class="other" id="scroll_making" data-link="violin-making">
        <div class="flex-container flex-menu-width">
            <div class="flex3 no-padding">
                <img src=" @asset('images/unmarked.png') " class="making">
                <span class="menu-content-adjust">Violin Making</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="is_active">
    <a href="/shop" class="other" id="scroll_shop_online" data-link="shop"><font color="red">
        <div class="flex-container flex-menu-width">
            <div class="flex3 no-padding">
                <img src=" @asset('images/unmarked.png') " class="online">
                <span class="menu-content-adjust" style="color: red;">SHOP Online</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </font></a>
    </div>
    <div class="is_active">
    <a href="/repairs-restorations" class="other" id="scroll_repairs" data-link="violin-repairs">
        <div class="flex-container flex-menu-width">
            <div class="flex3 no-padding">
                <img src=" @asset('images/unmarked.png') " class="repair">
                <span class="menu-content-adjust">Violin Repairs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="is_active">
        <a href="/endeavour-violins" class="other" id="scroll_endeavour" data-link="endeavour-violins">
            <div class="flex-container flex-menu-width">
                <div class="flex3 no-padding">
                    <img src=" @asset('images/unmarked.png') " class="endeavour">
                    <span class="menu-content-adjust">Endeavour Violins</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="is_active">
    <a href="/m-u-d" class="other" id="scroll_mud" data-link="mud">
        <div class="flex-container flex-menu-width">
            <div class="flex3 no-padding">
                <img src=" @asset('images/unmarked.png') " class="mud">
                <span class="menu-content-adjust">M.U.D.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="is_active">
    <a href="/faq" class="other" id="scroll_faq" data-link="faq">
        <div class="flex-container flex-menu-width">
            <div class="flex3 no-padding">
                <img src=" @asset('images/unmarked.png') " class="faq">
                <span class="menu-content-adjust">F.A.Q.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    var imagelink2 = "@asset('images/unmarked.png')";
    var imagelink = "@asset('images/marked.png')";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
        console.log(typeof pagename);
        if(typeof pagename != 'undefined'){
            path = pagename;
        }
        menuActive(path);
    });

    function menuActive(path){

        if(path == ''){
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .contact-menu').css({ "margin-top": "10px"});
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .contact-menu').attr( 'src', imagelink );
        }else{
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .contact-menu').removeAttr('style');
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .contact-menu').attr( 'src', imagelink2 );
        }
        
        
        if(path == "luthier"){
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .luthier-menu').css({ "margin-top": "10px"});
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .luthier-menu').attr( 'src', imagelink );
        }else{
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .luthier-menu').removeAttr('style');
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .luthier-menu').attr( 'src', imagelink2 );
        }
        
        if(path == "violin-making"){
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .making').css({ "margin-top": "10px"});
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .making').attr( 'src', imagelink );
        }else{
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .making').removeAttr('style');
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .making').attr( 'src', imagelink2 );
        }
        if(path == "shop"){
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .online').css({ "margin-top": "10px"});
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .online').attr( 'src', imagelink );
        }else{
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .online').removeAttr('style');
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .online').attr( 'src', imagelink2 );
        }
        if(path == "violin-repairs"){
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .repair').css({ "margin-top": "10px"});
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .repair').attr( 'src', imagelink );
        }else{
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .repair').removeAttr('style');
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .repair').attr( 'src', imagelink2 );
        }
        if(path == "endeavour-violins"){
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .endeavour').css({ "margin-top": "10px"});
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .endeavour').attr( 'src', imagelink );
        }else{
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .endeavour').removeAttr('style');
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .endeavour').attr( 'src', imagelink2 );
        }
        if(path == "mud"){
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .mud').css({ "margin-top": "10px"});
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .mud').attr( 'src', imagelink );
        }else{
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .mud').removeAttr('style');
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .mud').attr( 'src', imagelink2 );
        }
        if(path == "faq"){
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .faq').css({ "margin-top": "10px"});

            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .faq').attr( 'src', imagelink );
        }else{
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .faq').removeAttr('style');
            $('.is_active a .flex-container .flex3 .faq').attr( 'src', imagelink2 );
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".is_active a").hover(function() {
            menuActive($(this).data('link'));
        }, function() {
            var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
            // alert(link);
            if(typeof pagename != 'undefined'){
                path = pagename;
            }
            menuActive(path);
        });
    });
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
            return false;
            });
        });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 44) return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```